# Firebase Crashlytics not working alongside DJI iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics, dji-sdk

I've added Firebase Crashlytics to my project. It will track and upload crashes if they happen before the point, that the DJI SDK is initialized in my app. But once DJI SDK is working in the app, none of the crashes are uploaded. 
Does the DJI iOS SDK have its own crash logging, which is catching all crashes once the DJI code starts to run inside an app?

So in short:
My app logs crashes if they happen before I call

```
[DJISDKManager registerAppWithDelegate:self];
[DJISDKManager startConnectionToProduct];
```

After that, something else seems to intercept them and I don't get to upload the crashs to Firebase Crashlytics.

*EDIT*
I've been attempting to debug this further. So I changed from Firebase Crashlytics to the Sentry.io service. I tested it in a small test iOS app, setup was easy and it logged crashes as you would expect.
I moved it to the app using the DJI SDK and it exhibits the same problem as Firebase Crashlytics where the DJI SDK is seemingly catching crashes as they never appear in the app past the point where I initialize the DJI Mobile SDK.
*EDIT*

Can you guys advise what is going on, please?

Many Thanks,
B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebaser here -

I don't know much about the DJI SDK, but it does sound like it's doing something along the lines of registering an exception handler of some sort (especially since you run into the same problems with Sentry), maybe even if it's not explicitly logging crashes. The behavior where another exception handler or crash reporter is being used causing Crashlytics to not report crashes, or vice versa, is known behavior to us. If you've ever tried to launch an app via Xcode and was unable to report crashes to Crashlytics because the Xcode debugger was attached at launch, I believe it's similar to that.

This may be a question worth asking the DJI team directly if they have a public issue tracker or a support email line open.